# Error: Cannot find module , code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', requireStack: []

Tags: express, mongoose, dbconnection

I saw a video about tinder clone on YouTube, I checked my code many time but it crashes when I run it.

The error that I get is, `code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'`. I run it with node and nodemon but it doesn't change.

I also tested with try and catch example,

`server.js`

```
import express from "express";
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import Cards from "./dbCards";

//app config
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8001;
const connection_url = 'mongodb+srv://admin:user@database.mongodb.net/tinderdb?retryWrites=true&w=majority'


// middlewares

// db config
mongoose.connect(connection_url);

//api endpoints 
app.get('/',(req,res)=>  res.status(200).send('hello clever'))

app.post("/tinder/cards", (req, res) => {
    const dbCard = req.body
    Cards.create(dbCard, (err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            res.status(500).send(err)
        } else {
            res.status(201).send(data)
        }
    })
})

app.get('/tinder/cards', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const allCards = await Cards.find();
      res.status(200).send(allCards); 
    } catch (error) { 
      res.status(500).send(error); 
    }
  });
// listener
app.listen(port , ()=>console.log(`lis terning on local host   ${port}`));
```

`dbCard.js`

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
 
const cardSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name:String,
    imgUrl:String,
   }
);
 
const Cards = mongoose.model('User', cardSchema);
 
export default Cards;
```

Comment: I tested './tinder/card'  like this but it doesnt change . and I change '.\dbCards' to '../dbCards' and the result was  in same .

Comment: internal/process/esm_loader.js:74
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Comment: this is what I receive

Comment: Could you post the whole text of the error? Or, at the very least, a screenshot of it (discouraged though)?

Answer (score 1):

finally , I find what cause an error in my app. the error code was `code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'`  . and it means you don't connect modules correctly .
the issue is express need the extension of file to recognize the modules . so if you import like `import Cards from "./dbCards.js";` .the error will be gone .